# Including table without relationship in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have controller where I am loading all invoices with following code.

```
  def index
    @invoices = Invoice.includes(:customer).all
  end
```

I have following Invoice and customer models

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer

  delegate :name,
           :street,
           :city,
           :state,
           :zip_code,
           to: :customer,
           prefix: true
end
```

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :address
  has_many :invoices

  delegate :street, :city, :state, :zip_code, to: :address
end
```

Now in my view I have following code

```
%tr
  = render partial: "row", locals: { data: invoice.id }
  = render partial: "row", locals: { data: invoice.customer_name }
  = render partial: "row", locals: { data: invoice.customer_street }
  = render partial: "row", locals: { data: invoice.customer_city }
  = render partial: "row", locals: { data: invoice.customer_state }
  = render partial: "row", locals: { data: invoice.customer_zip_code }
```

As I am using address it is doing N+1 I have include customer in following lines

```
@invoices = Invoice.includes(:customer).all
```

But how do I add address in it, so no N+1 query for address come up. As now I have fix customer and only two queries coming but I need to add Address in it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@invoices = Invoice.includes(customer: :address).all`

To each invoice include customer and to each customer include address.

Comment: Awesome but what it mean by `customer: :address` and I tried `:customer, :address` but it did not work.

Comment: `(customer: :address)` is a `Hash`. The {} are optional in ruby in a lot of places. Another way to write that would be `.includes({ :customer => :address })`. Check the docs for includes for more info as well. https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes